# How to generate and run native code dynamically?

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, x86, jit

I'd like to write a very small proof-of-concept JIT compiler for a toy language processor I've written (purely academic), but I'm having some trouble in the middle-altitudes of design.  Conceptually, I'm familiar with how JIT works - you compile bytecode into (machine or assembly?) code to run.  At the nuts-and-bolts level however, I'm not quite gripping *how* you actually go about *doing* that.

My (very "newb") knee-jerk reaction, since I haven't the first clue where to start, would be to try something like the following:

1. mmap() a block of memory, setting access to PROT_EXEC
2. write the native code into the block
3. store the current registers (stack pointer, et al.) someplace cozy
4. modify the current registers to point into the native code block in the mapped region
5. the native code would now get executed by the machine
6. restore the previous registers

Is that even *close* to a/the correct algorithm?  I've tried perusing different projects that I know have JIT compilers to study (such as [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/)) but these codebases turn out to be difficult to consume because of their size, and I've little idea where to start looking.

Comment: You can probably simplify things further: you can often just take the starting address of your code within the `mmap`'ed block and cast it to a function pointer.  In that case, the code would need to save and restore its own registers and such.  You would want to look at the calling conventions in your platforms ABI (Application Binary Interface) for exactly what you need to save (and how to get arguments from C code, call C functions, etc.).

Comment: Not that I have that much experience with this, but you might way to check out PiPi's python interpreter. I've looked through the CPython interpreter and it's pretty good to read.

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock: It seems to me like that's roughly the technique demonstrated by @Shelwien below, am I correct?

Comment: mmap to PROT_EXEC will probably not work. I don't believe current versions of Linux allow any memory to be both writable and executable at the same time. You need to map it writable, write it, then map it executable. Or so I believe.

Comment: Actually it seems to be working just fine in my experiment thus far.  I'm using a recent build of the kernel (2.6.35) and setting my `mmap()` access rights with `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC`

Comment: @Chris: I guess it works for you. I know it didn't work for me. It might have been a Gentoo secure kernel. You might run into trouble on some systems.

Comment: Not that you're targeting non-x86, but beware that self modifying code (or on-the-fly generated code) requires explicit cache synchronization on other platforms. It's pretty much just x86 which does it transparently (which means loads of silicon). Just call msync() on the buffer after finishing writing and before executing it.

Comment: @John Ripley: Thanks for the advice.  That'd be a tough one to debug!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not sure about linux, but this works on x86/windows.
Update: http://codepad.org/sQoF6kR8

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

int arg1;
int arg2;
int res1;

typedef void (*pfunc)(void);

union funcptr {
  pfunc x;
  byte* y;
};

int main( void ) {

  byte* buf = (byte*)VirtualAllocEx( GetCurrentProcess(), 0, 1<<16, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE );

  if( buf==0 ) return 0;

  byte* p = buf;

  *p++ = 0x50; // push eax
  *p++ = 0x52; // push edx

  *p++ = 0xA1; // mov eax, [arg2]
  (int*&)p[0] = &arg2; p+=sizeof(int*);

  *p++ = 0x92; // xchg edx,eax

  *p++ = 0xA1; // mov eax, [arg1]
  (int*&)p[0] = &arg1; p+=sizeof(int*);

  *p++ = 0xF7; *p++ = 0xEA; // imul edx

  *p++ = 0xA3; // mov [res1],eax
  (int*&)p[0] = &res1; p+=sizeof(int*);

  *p++ = 0x5A; // pop edx
  *p++ = 0x58; // pop eax
  *p++ = 0xC3; // ret

  funcptr func;
  func.y = buf;

  arg1 = 123; arg2 = 321; res1 = 0;

  func.x(); // call generated code

  printf( "arg1=%i arg2=%i arg1*arg2=%i func(arg1,arg2)=%i\n", arg1,arg2,arg1*arg2,res1 );

}
```

Comment: @Shelwien: It was most definitely not portable before, since most modern OS's would not accept execution of the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the great example!  I very nearly didn't catch that `funcptr` was a `union` at first - after that it made perfect sense.

Comment: First version used a simple typecast there, like ((pfunc)(void*)buf)(); , but codepad said something about ISO C++ not allowing to cast random stuff to functions, so i had to replace it with a union.

Comment: What would be the modification(s) required to work on x64?  I'm not an assembly expert, but I don't see anything that x64 wouldn't find reverse-compatible.

Comment: I meant that the generated code there is 32-bit, x64 code would be different. I can make a x64 version if necessary, but is it?

Comment: No, not at all - it was simply my [mis]understanding that 32 bit code could run on a 64 bit machine with little or no modification.

Comment: Anyway, updated to a "universal" version. Previous one wasn't compatible because x64 doesn't have PUSHA/POPA, nor IMUL r32,[m64]

Comment: I see.  I translated this code for Linux (basically just swapped your `VirtualAllocEx` for an `mmap`) and she works like a charm!

Comment: @Shelwien: I have thought that tricks like above should only be available for system to block polymorphic viruses. But on the other side virtual machines won't be able to make translation of the program being interpreted into machine codes on the fly.

Comment: Polymorphic viruses don't have to execute generated code in memory, generated code is used to infect another machine, so blocking of data execution won't help much.

Answer (score 5):

Youmay want to have a look at *libjit* which provides exactly the infrastructure you're looking for:

> The libjit library implements
>   just-in-time compilation
>   functionality. Unlike other JITs, this
>   one is designed to be independent of
>   any particular virtual machine
>   bytecode format or language.

http://freshmeat.net/projects/libjit

Comment: Interesting find.  This may well be useful if I decide I ever actually want to implement a non-trivial JIT.

Answer (score 4):

The Android Dalvik JIT compiler might also be worth looking at. It is supposed to be fairly small and lean (not sure if this helps understanding it or makes things more complicated). It targets Linux as well.

If things are getting more serious, looking at LLVM might be a good choice as well.

The function pointer approach suggested by Jeremiah sounds good. You may want to use the caller's stack anyway and there will probably only be a few registers left (on x86) which you need to preserve or not touch. In this case, it is probably easiest if your compiled code (or the entry stub) saves them on the stack before proceeding. In the end, it all boils down to writing an assembler function and interfacing to it from C.

Answer (score 4):

[How to JIT - an introduction](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/11/05/how-to-jit-an-introduction/) is a new article (from today!) that addresses some of these issues and describes the bigger picture as well.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on your compiler and where you put the code. See http://encode.ru/threads/1273-Just-In-Time-Compilation-Improvement-For-ZPAQ?p=24902&posted=1#post24902

Testing in 32 bit Vista, Visual C++ gives a DEP (data execution prevention) error whether the code is put on the stack, heap, or static memory. g++, Borland, and Mars can be made to work sometimes. Data accessed by the JIT code needs to be declared volatile.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the techniques suggested so far, it might be worthwhile to look into the thread creation functions. If you create a new thread, with the starting address set to your generated code, you know for sure that there are no old registers that need saving or restoring, and the OS handles the setup of the relevant registers for you. I.e you eliminate steps 3, 4 and 6 of your list.

Comment: The only thing I would hesitate on here is that with threads, you then have to deal with synchronization, et al. - otherwise (if synchronization can be ignored and/or deferred) that's a pretty clever idea.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [why the lucky stiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_the_lucky_stiff)'s [Potion](https://github.com/fogus/potion) programming language. It's a small, incomplete language that features just-in-time compilation. Potion's small size makes it easier to understand. The repository includes a description of the [language's internals](https://github.com/fogus/potion/blob/master/INTERNALS.md) (JIT content starts at heading "**~ the jit ~**").

The implementation is complicated by the fact it runs in the context of [Potion's VM](https://github.com/fogus/potion/blob/master/core/vm.c). Don't let this scare you off, though. It doesn't take long to see what he's up to. Basically, using a small set of VM opcodes allows some actions to be modeled as [optimized assembly](https://github.com/fogus/potion/blob/master/core/vm-x86.c).

Answer (score 0):

**Linux x86 `mmap` minimal example**

Just to provide a Linux one with `mmap`. At runtime I inject into memory a function equivalent to:

```
int ing(int i) {
    return i + 1;
}
```

main.c

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h> /* NULL */
#include <sys/mman.h> /* mmap, munmap */

union funcptr {
    int (*f)(int);
    unsigned char *bytes;
};

int main(void) {
    unsigned char *buf = (unsigned char *)mmap(NULL, 4, PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    assert(buf != MAP_FAILED);
    unsigned char *p = buf;

    // return i + 1;
    // lea 0x1(%rdi),%eax
    *p++ = 0x8d;
    *p++ = 0x47;
    *p++ = 0x01;

    // ret
    *p++ = 0xC3;

    assert(((union funcptr){ .bytes = buf }).f(1) == 2);

    // Just to check if we can modify the code witout any explicit icache flushing.
    // return i + 2;
    // lea 0x1(%rdi),%eax
    buf[2] = 0x02;

    assert(((union funcptr){ .bytes = buf }).f(1) == 3);

    int ret = munmap(buf, 4);
    assert(!ret);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main main.c
./main
```

I use an `union` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912662/895245 because the C standard apparently forbids casting non function pointers to function pointers: [ISO C Void * and Function Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134245/iso-c-void-and-function-pointers) This is a bit paternalistic, and if you ignore the warning GCC can also just cast directly with:

```
assert(((int (*)(int))(buf))(1) == 2);
```

The shell code was obtained by compiling a test file:

notmain.c

```
int inc(int i) {
    return i + 1;
}
```

with `-O3` and disassembling it:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -o notmain.o notmain.c
objdump -d notmain.o
```

and the output contains:

```
0000000000000000 <inc>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
   4:   8d 47 01                lea    0x1(%rdi),%eax
   7:   c3                      ret
```

The `endbr64` is a NOP/security feature, so we can ("un"safely) ignore it: [What does the endbr64 instruction actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56905811/what-does-the-endbr64-instruction-actually-do)

Related:

- [Is it possible to create a function dynamically, during runtime in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016078/is-it-possible-to-create-a-function-dynamically-during-runtime-in-c)
- [How to compile and execute from memory directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690454/how-to-compile-and-execute-from-memory-directly?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Tested on Ubuntu 23.10 amd64.

Comment: ISO C still doesn't define the behaviour of type-punning non-function pointers to function-pointers, a union or `memcpy` is just hiding it from the compiler.  Probably most readable if you do something like `int (*fptr)(int) = (void*)buf;` in C.  GCC `-Wall` doesn't warn about that, nor about `int (*fptr)(int) = reinterpret_cast<int (*)(int)>(buf);` - https://godbolt.org/z/M9Kr6d9hv

Comment: GNU C *does* define the behaviour, but you have to use `__builtin___clear_cache(buf, buf+3);` to be sure the compiler won't do dead-store elimination.  (Casting to function pointer and calling through it doesn't get treated as "used".  In this case it doesn't get optimized away because it doesn't know how `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` works: it's a pointer to memory that could be globally reachable some other way, so has to be in sync before an opaque function call.  (In case the called function reads those bytes as data.  Reading them as code just happens to work).

Comment: Despite the name, `__builtin___clear_cache` doesn't actually do anything to cache on x86, only on ISAs without coherent I-cache.  On x86 it just blocks dead-store elimination and similar reordering of stores.  See [How does \_\_builtin\_\_\_clear\_cache work?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/85964322) / https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GvKPzYvo5 - in a `-zexecstack` build on an older system where that uses READ_IMPLIES_EXEC, so `malloc` returns executable memory, you actually do need `__builtin___clear_cache` because GCC knows about `malloc`.  Or maybe if you `mprotect` some stack mem?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/5671x3MYn is a better example, using a stack buffer with `-zexecstack` which still works on modern kernels.  It shows dead store elimination leading to a jump to uninitialized stack space vs. with clear_cache a working program.  See also [execute binary machine code from C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18476002) / [How to get c code to execute hex machine code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9960721)

Comment: Also, `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` makes GCC / Glibc choose not to define `MAP_ANONYMOUS` when compiling as C on Godbolt (but works as C++).  Leaving it out works, but perhaps there's a higher version number that's appropriate.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for these comments, Peter! Long time no see!