# Trying to execute any binary from c

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly

I followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476002/execute-binary-machine-code-from-c) in order to execute some binary code.

The tinky_winky's answer, while worked when I did try to execute another binary file didn't worked.

For example I wrote this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
   printf("Prueba\n");
   return(0);
}
```

compiled with gcc (without any parameters) and then put the generated binary on the code variable

```
char code[] = {0x7f,0x45,0x4c,0x46,0x02,0x01,0x01,0x00,0x00,...};
```

and then tried to compile the new file, but got segmentation fault error.

It is possible to actually run any kind of arbitrary code within c (or c++) or it is only possible to run functions in bare asm code (like in the original thread)?

Comment: Things are far more complicated than you think. A executable file contains more than machine code. For executing an executable file (binary) the operating systems loads the file into memory and does a lot of complicated things before the actual execution of the code takes place.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly implementation specific, practically dependent upon your [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and processor [instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) (and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) & [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention)).

<sup>(I guess and hope you are on Linux; but your question is unclear)</sup>

On Linux/x86_64, most of the memory in your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) is *not* executable (for security reasons). Try running your program with [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the relevant system calls. Also use the debugger `gdb`. You may need to make the segment containing your binary code executable, e.g. with [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html). If your process is 1234, try `cat /proc/1234/maps` in some other terminal (to query its virtual address space). Read more about [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for details.

Perhaps you should consider [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) techniques and libraries like [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit), [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), etc...

BTW, an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable file is quite complex, and does not start with executable [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code). Read also [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html). Use [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) & [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) to explore and understand ELF executables. This might explain why your experiment failed (but we don't know how did you come with `char code[] = {0x7f,0x45,0x4c,0x46` .... these few bytes look like some ELF header)

You probably should *carefully* extract some functions (i.e. their machine code & data) from your ELF executable and deal with [relocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29) (and [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), for C++), if you want to continue your experiment. Reading Levine's book on [*Linkers & Loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can run such hex code but you cannot get an executable file without modifications. There is file prefix which is for the OS and is not assembly opcodes.

Comment: Please clarify "file prefix".  What OSes use a file prefix?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Read about ELF (Linux) or PE (Windows) file format. There is structure with executable info in the beginning in addition to real executable instructions. In short it can be called "prefix". Do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is on your pc or laptop or whatever computer you are reading this webpage on.   Each program is prevented from running arbitrary code in memory, or even accessing code outside its space.   you have a program and you have data in an array, which you may know to be instructions but the operating system and the compiler, etc know to be data.  So you have to talk to the operating system to ask it to allow you to execute that code.  Search for self modifying code here at stackoverflow or on the net.  probably want to use mmap() if running on linux.

Comment: if running bare metal on a microcontroller for example, then you can simply branch to the array of instructions and it should work just fine (well so long as they are aligned right and are actually instructions that terminate properly or end in a loop.