# I couldn't read text section from binary using capstone library

Tags: c, x86, disassembly, capstone

I have a small binary which is only prints "hello", and I export .text section, using libbfd and readelf's command
`readelf -x .text a.out` both of them gave me this output

```
f3 0f 1e fa 31 ed 49 89 d1 5e 48 89 e2 48 83 e4 f0 50 54 4c 8d 05 66 01 00 00 48 8d 0d ef 00 00 00 48 8d 3d c1 00 00 00 ff 15 52 2f 00 00 f4 90 48 8d 3d 79 2f 00 00 48 8d 05 72 2f 00 00 48 39 f8 74 15 48 8b 05 2e 2f 00 00 48 85 c0 74 09 ff e0 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 c3 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 48 8d 3d 49 2f 00 00 48 8d 35 42 2f 00 00 48 29 fe 48 89 f0 48 c1 ee 3f 48 c1 f8 03 48 01 c6 48 d1 fe 74 14 48 8b 05 05 2f 00 00 48 85 c0 74 08 ff e0 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 c3 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 80 3d 05 2f 00 00 00 75 2b 55 48 83 3d e2 2e 00 00 00 48 89 e5 74 0c 48 8b 3d e6 2e 00 00 e8 19 ff ff ff e8 64 ff ff ff c6 05 dd 2e 00 00 01 5d c3 0f 1f 00 c3 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa e9 77 ff ff ff f3 0f 1e fa 55 48 89 e5 48 8d 3d ac 0e 00 00 b8 00 00 00 00 e8 ee fe ff ff b8 00 00 00 00 5d c3 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 41 57 4c 8d 3d 3b 2c 00 00 41 56 49 89 d6 41 55 49 89 f5 41 54 41 89 fc 55 48 8d 2d 2c 2c 00 00 53 4c 29 fd 48 83 ec 08 e8 5f fe ff ff 48 c1 fd 03 74 1f 31 db 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 4c 89 f2 4c 89 ee 44 89 e7 41 ff 14 df 48 83 c3 01 48 39 dd 75 ea 48 83 c4 08 5b 5d 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f c3 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa c3
```

I use an [online disassembler](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm) and it is able to disassemble it, but with this code using [capstone](https://www.capstone-engine.org/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <capstone/capstone.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    csh dis;
    cs_insn *insns;

    size_t n;

    if(cs_open(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_64, &dis) != CS_ERR_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "Faild to open Capstone\n");
        return -1;
    }

    uint8_t code []= { 0xF3, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0xFA, 0x31, 0xED, 0x49, 0x89, 0xD1, 0x5E, 0x48, 0x89, 0xE2, 0x48, 0x83, 0xE4, 0xF0, 0x50, 0x54, 0x4C, 0x8D, 0x05, 0x66, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x8D, 0x0D, 0xEF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x8D, 0x3D, 0xC1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x15, 0x52, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF4, 0x90, 0x48, 0x8D, 0x3D, 0x79, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x8D, 0x05, 0x72, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x39, 0xF8, 0x74, 0x15, 0x48, 0x8B, 0x05, 0x2E, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x85, 0xC0, 0x74, 0x09, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x0F, 0x1F, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x0F, 0x1F, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x8D, 0x3D, 0x49, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x8D, 0x35, 0x42, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x29, 0xFE, 0x48, 0x89, 0xF0, 0x48, 0xC1, 0xEE, 0x3F, 0x48, 0xC1, 0xF8, 0x03, 0x48, 0x01, 0xC6, 0x48, 0xD1, 0xFE, 0x74, 0x14, 0x48, 0x8B, 0x05, 0x05, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x85, 0xC0, 0x74, 0x08, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x66, 0x0F, 0x1F, 0x44, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x0F, 0x1F, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF3, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0xFA, 0x80, 0x3D, 0x05, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x75, 0x2B, 0x55, 0x48, 0x83, 0x3D, 0xE2, 0x2E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x89, 0xE5, 0x74, 0x0C, 0x48, 0x8B, 0x3D, 0xE6, 0x2E, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE8, 0x19, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE8, 0x64, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xC6, 0x05, 0xDD, 0x2E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x5D, 0xC3, 0x0F, 0x1F, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x0F, 0x1F, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF3, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0xFA, 0xE9, 0x77, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF3, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0xFA, 0x55, 0x48, 0x89, 0xE5, 0x48, 0x8D, 0x3D, 0xAC, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE8, 0xEE, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xB8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x5D, 0xC3, 0x0F, 0x1F, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF3, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0xFA, 0x41, 0x57, 0x4C, 0x8D, 0x3D, 0x3B, 0x2C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x56, 0x49, 0x89, 0xD6, 0x41, 0x55, 0x49, 0x89, 0xF5, 0x41, 0x54, 0x41, 0x89, 0xFC, 0x55, 0x48, 0x8D, 0x2D, 0x2C, 0x2C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x53, 0x4C, 0x29, 0xFD, 0x48, 0x83, 0xEC, 0x08, 0xE8, 0x5F, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x48, 0xC1, 0xFD, 0x03, 0x74, 0x1F, 0x31, 0xDB, 0x0F, 0x1F, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4C, 0x89, 0xF2, 0x4C, 0x89, 0xEE, 0x44, 0x89, 0xE7, 0x41, 0xFF, 0x14, 0xDF, 0x48, 0x83, 0xC3, 0x01, 0x48, 0x39, 0xDD, 0x75, 0xEA, 0x48, 0x83, 0xC4, 0x08, 0x5B, 0x5D, 0x41, 0x5C, 0x41, 0x5D, 0x41, 0x5E, 0x41, 0x5F, 0xC3, 0x66, 0x66, 0x2E, 0x0F, 0x1F, 0x84, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF3, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0xFA, 0xC3 };

    n = cs_disasm(dis, code, sizeof(code), 0x2000, 0, &insns);
    if(n <= 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Disassembly error: %s\n", cs_strerror(cs_errno(dis)));
        return -1;
        }


    for(size_t i =0 ; i < n ; i++){
        printf("0x%016jx: ", insns[i].address);
        for(size_t j = 0; j < 16; j++){
            if(j < insns[i].size) printf("%02x ", insns[i].bytes[j]);
            else printf("    ");
        }
       printf("%-12s %s\n", insns[i].mnemonic, insns[i].op_str);
    }
    cs_free(insns, n);
    cs_close(&dis);

    return 0;
    return 0;
}
```

then I build it with gcc `gcc disas.c -lcapstone`

after running this code I'll always get this output:

`Disassembly error: OK (CS_ERR_OK)`
from this line `fprintf(stderr, "Disassembly error: %s\n", cs_strerror(cs_errno(dis)));`
and this function `n = cs_disasm(dis, code, sizeof(code), 0x2000, 0, &insns);` always returns zero which is indicates that it did not disassemble and thing, any solution?

Comment: What is this value: `0x2000`?

Comment: @kiner_shah the behavior of cs_disasm is to return the number of disassembled instructions and you can check here almost the same condition from the doc https://www.capstone-engine.org/lang_c.html, also here the explanation of the function behavior from rust version of the documentation https://docs.rs/capstone-sys/0.2.0/capstone_sys/fn.cs_disasm.html

Comment: @kiner_shah starting address of the instructions in the virtual memory

Comment: `0x2000` seems to be address of first instruction. How did you get that value?

Comment: @kiner_shah in this is snippet is hard-coded which is fine

Comment: Since `cs_disasm` is returning `0` which means error and `errno` is set to `CS_ERR_OK` which means no error (everything was OK). That means probably a bug in the library. Maybe you should report the library maintainers about this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is (was) definitely a bug or missing feature in libcapstone. I was able to track it down using `git bisect` after cloning from [the official repository](https://github.com/libcapstone/libcapstone) and compiling the library by myself each bisection step. It seems like the first commit where `cs_disasm` actually becomes able to disassemble your code is [`5a99624074d56f8eea26699496f0e8dc41cbf3fb`](https://github.com/libcapstone/libcapstone/commit/5a99624074d56f8eea26699496f0e8dc41cbf3fb) which is somewhere after version 4.0.1.

Indeed, using the latest version of libcapstone built directly from their `main` branch your code works just fine and produces (with a bit less padding):

```
0x0000000000002000: f3 0f 1e fa     endbr64
0x0000000000002004: 31 ed           xor          ebp, ebp
0x0000000000002006: 49 89 d1        mov          r9, rdx
0x0000000000002009: 5e              pop          rsi
0x000000000000200a: 48 89 e2        mov          rdx, rsp
0x000000000000200d: 48 83 e4 f0     and          rsp, 0xfffffffffffffff0
...
```

The incriminated instruction which was not correctly decoded is that first `endbr64` (your linked online assembler decodes it as a `nop`, which is also correct), [see this other question for more info about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56905811/3889449).

Comment: I didn't know about `bisect`. I'm therefore interested in knowing how long, from start to finish, it took you to identify the commit. Not 9 days as implied by date of the OP and your answer, right?

Comment: @JeffHolt nah, took me less than 10 minutes to bisect after figuring out how to build the library. `git bisect` does a binary search so it's pretty fast to track down the commit you are looking for (took me 9 steps IIRC), you can take a look at [this documentation page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) which explains how it works with some easy examples.